# type checking without hardcoding type or storing type information in array

Tags: go

I'm trying to figure does go provides an option to avoid hardcoding type in the switch branch without reflection or run-time type checking.

The idea here GetGeneric shouldn't know anything about the type it receives.  The caller tells to GetGeneric use type X,  GetGeneric pass
to stmt.Get that populate a model data.

In code below stmt.Get requires & of a type to be concrete type.
Here is a small example. But I really don't like that I need a hardcode
type for each model as a seperare case branch and it defeats the entire purpose, and I'm restricted on an interface that stmt.Get provides.

```
func (pdb *PersistentDb) GetGeneric(ctx context.Context, sqlStmt string,
    model interface{}, args ...interface{}) (interface{}, error) {

    if pdb == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("you need to initilize persistent db first")
    }

    db, err := pdb.connectx(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        callistolog.Errorf("Failed connect to database error: %v", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    defer db.Close()

    stmt, errPrepare := db.Preparex(sqlStmt)
    if errPrepare != nil {
        callistolog.Errorf("Failed prepare sql statement error: %v", errPrepare)
        return nil, errPrepare
    }
    defer stmt.Close()

    switch t := model.(type) {
    case models.Role:
        err = stmt.Get(&t, args...)
        return t, err
    case models.Tenants:
        err = stmt.Get(&t, args...)
        return t, err
    // here for each models.Type I need add branch
    default:
        callistolog.Errorf("got unknown type")
    }

    return model, fmt.Errorf("unknown type")
}
```

One option a run-time check via reflection, but I was thinking
can I declare somehow array/slice of types and optimize switch branch
to if branch, and in the loop iterate.

Something like ( pseudocode)

if type T in an array of models.
take T as generic and make it concrete type T_hat
pass T_hat address to stmt.Get

In some language, you can have an array of Object[], etc
and you can check the object type.

In this example, the caller provides a model as a generic interface
and inside a GetGeneric model type-checked to concrete type based on the fact if that type in an array of known types and if it is t become concret so stmt.Get accepts that.

For example,

How I can store type information not a value in slice and then dispatch to
stmt.Get(&t, args...)

```
    types := []interface{} {model, model1, model2}
    for _,v := range types {

    }
```

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, but maybe you want `err = stmt.Get(reflect.ValueOf(t).Addr().Interface(), args...)`.

Comment: As Go has no type casts at all the question as states makes not much sense and type switches are used to switch on a defined type and using them on a variable set of  types is nonsensical too.

Comment: @Volker, you are correct. I guess the correct way to formulate a question, get the type. My mistake.

Comment: @PaulHankin thank you.  but if I want  something like modles := []interface{} {models.A, models.B, modelC}
In essence, store in models, type information, not value, and in the loop check type without runtime check but static check.  My understanding reflects a run-time check.

Comment: Perhaps you want a "New()" method on your model types that returns a pointer to a zero-initialized model? `type Model interface {New() interface{}}`. Then your code can read "err=stmt.Get(model.New(), args...)`.

Comment: If you question is "how can I write a type switch statement without hard-coding the types"  then you can't (without using reflect).

Comment: @PaulHankin I think that will do a job. I need to check.   The idea in essence.  Get Generic shouldn't know anything about the type it receives. Caller tells a type GetGeneric should use.  it just passes that to stmt.Get,  stmt.Get does what it does and returns back to a caller instance of that type. So GetGeneric just needs to know a type that the caller requested and pass that and return an instance of that type.  But approach makeYourself (as factory method) as interface might do a job.

Comment: Can't you make GetGeneric's caller pass a pointer and just call stmt.Get(t, args...)? You can get rid of the annoying interface{} return value too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using [`sqlx`](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#Stmt.Get)  adding another layer of reflection just makes no sense, instead use it as it was designed to be used.

```golang
func (pdb *PersistentDb) GetGeneric(ctx context.Context, sqlStmt string, model interface{}, args ...interface{}) error {
    if pdb == nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("you need to initilize persistent db first")
    }

    db, err := pdb.connectx(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        callistolog.Errorf("Failed connect to database error: %v", err)
        return err
    }
    defer db.Close()

    stmt, errPrepare := db.Preparex(sqlStmt)
    if errPrepare != nil {
        callistolog.Errorf("Failed prepare sql statement error: %v", errPrepare)
        return errPrepare
    }
    defer stmt.Close()

    if err := stmt.Get(model, args...)
        callistolog.Error(err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

```golang
role := models.Role{}
if err := pdb.GetGeneric(ctx, "select ...", &role, args...); err != nil {
    return err
}
fmt.Println(role)

// ...

tentants := models.Tenants{}
if err := pdb.GetGeneric(ctx, "select ...", &tenants, args...); err != nil {
    return err
}
fmt.Println(tentants)
```

---

Note that preparing a statement manually is unnecessary if you don't intend to reuse it.